# upload image displays an error under drupal 6

Tags: drupal

A site have run ok for some time. But recently, when I upload a image, it is always raising this error:

> An unrecoverable error occurred. This form was missing from the server cache. Try reloading the page and submitting again.

The first time i uploaded the image is ok. but when I create the second article and upload a image, it shows the above error. And the upload button disappeared.

Does anyone konw how to correct it and what's the reason of this error emergence ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is not Drupal. Most likely a setting on the server. If you use hosting services. please contact support, they may be something advise. Also recommend looking into the FAQ page the module loads the image coordinates.

Also, to test this problem, try to move the website to your local kompyuter and test does not appear whether this problem. Good luck. And update all the modules before actual sosoyaniya. Poeksprimentiruyte module load module dev.

Answer (score 1):

Some other users have had the same sort of issue.  See [this](http://drupal.org/node/500646) thread on Drupal.org and this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6176/an-unrecoverable-error-occurred) at Drupal Answers.

Try to disabling caching under `admin/settings/performance` and set minimum lifetime to none.  Also try clearing the caches on your site *and* in your browser and try again.

Comment: disable caching under admin/settings/performance and set minimum lifetime to none.this can solve the problem. but not a good ways to solve the question.if i want to set cache to my site.how do i do? thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `cache_get()` function inside `includes/cache.inc` file.
At line no. 42, there is a check :

```
 if (isset($user->cache) && $user->cache > $cache->created)
```

Time of user cache, is always coming as bigger than cache's creation time. That is why, this function returning zero and file is not uploaded.

However I could not find the solution yet.